# Polish subgroups of $S_\infty$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, permutations, topological-groups, descriptive-set-theory

Let $S_\infty$ considered as Polish Group. Prove that every Polish subgroup of $S_\infty$ has the following form: $\overline{{\left \langle X \right \rangle}}$, where $X$ is a countable subset of $S_\infty$.

I tried using the known facts that every Polish subspace is a $G_\delta$ set and that the closure of an intersection is contained in the intersection of the closures, but without success.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is to show that a Polish subgroup of a Polish group is closed.

Thus let $H \subset S_{\infty}$ be a Polish subgroup, and let $K = \overline{H}$. The closure of a subgroup is a subgroup in every topological group, so $K$ is a closed subgroup of $S_{\infty}$. In metrisable spaces, every closed set is a $G_{\delta}$, so $K$ is Polish. Since $H$ is a Polish subspace of $K$, it is a $G_{\delta}$ in $K$. Polish spaces are Baire spaces, and $H$ is dense in $K$, therefore $K \setminus H$ is meagre. But $K\setminus H$ is the union of cosets of $H$ is $K$, and translations are homeomorphisms, so if $K \setminus H$ were nonempty, $H$ itself would be meagre (as a subset of a meagre subset of $K$). But then $K = H \cup (K\setminus H)$ would be meagre, contradicting Baire's theorem. It follows that $K = H$, i.e. $H$ is closed.

And as a Polish space, $H$ is separable. So let $X$ be a countable dense subset of $H$, then $H = \overline{\langle X\rangle}$.

Comment: Sorry I need some explanations: 1) why $K\setminus H$ is meagre in $K$? 2) you mean that $K\setminus H=\bigcup (Hk|k\not \in H)$ right? 3) why if $K\setminus H$ we nonempty then $H$ would be meagre? 4) At the end, if $K$ would be meager what is the contradiction? we know that an open set cannot be a meager in a Baire space. Thank you very much

Comment: Ad 1), $H$ is a dense $G_{\delta}$, $H = \bigcap_n U_n$. Each of the $U_n$ is dense (since it contains the dense subset $H$), so $K\setminus U_n$ is a closed subset with empty interior, in particular, $K\setminus U_n$ is nowhere dense. And $K \setminus H = \bigcup_n (K\setminus U_n)$ is hence a countable union of nowhere dense sets, i.e. meagre. Ad 2) yes. Ad 3), suppose $k\in K\setminus H$. Then $Hk \subset K\setminus H$, so $Hk$ is meagre as a subset of a meagre set. But $x \mapsto xk^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism, so $H = (Hk)k^{-1}$ is meagre too.

Comment: Ad 4), as a Polish space, $K$ is non-meagre (of the second category in itself) by Baire's theorem [$K$ is completely metrisable] (with your final note: $K$ is open in itself).

Comment: A question about 3), the others are ok. If $k\in K\setminus H$ then it means that there is a set $Hg$ with $g\not\in H$ and $k\in Hg$. Why $Hg$ should be exactly $Hk$? Last thing: are you sure that a subset of a meagre set is meagre?

Comment: Two cosets of a subgroup are either disjoint or equal. Since $k \in Hk$, if $k\in Hg$, then $Hk \cap Hg \neq \varnothing$, and therefore $Hk = Hg$. /// A subset of a nowhere dense set is nowhere dense - $A \subset B \implies \overline{A}\subset \overline{B} \implies \operatorname{int}(\overline{A}) \subset \operatorname{int}(\overline{B})$, and so if $B$ is nowhere dense, i.e. $\operatorname{int}(\overline{B}) = \varnothing$, $A$ must be nowhere dense too. Then if $B = \bigcup_n C_n$ with nowhere dense $C_n$, and $A\subset B$, we have $A = \bigcup_n (C_n\cap A)$.

Comment: And so $A$ is a countable union of nowhere dense sets too, i.e. meagre.

Comment: Got it, thank you again